# serialise a c# datatable with a hierarchy as json heirachy

Tags: c#, json.net, hierarchy

I have a dataTable with the following data in it:

```
Parent  Child
Dan     Heidi
Dan     Lauren
Alan    Dan
Daphne  Alan
Alan    Lorna
Alan    Tim
```

I want to output the following json:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'Daphne',
    'children': [
      {
        'name': 'Alan',
        'children': [
          {
            'name': 'Dan',
            'children': [
              {
                'name': 'Heidi'
              },
              {
                'name': 'Lauren'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            'name': 'Tim'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Lorna'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've used the json.net serialiser to serialse one level in the hierarchy, I would have thought this was a common problem. Is there a simple way to convert a datTable with a hierarchy to a json string with a hierarchy?

I guess the key bit is identifying how many and which levels there are in the hierarchy, ive looked at the hierarchyid datatype in sql server but it seems a bit messy to need that.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Newtonsoft.JSON can definitely serialize multi-layer objects. Have you tried re-building the data table as a anonymous type?

Comment: How would I build the table as anonymous type?

Comment: I misspoke, I don't think you can go from a datatable to an anonymous type, at least not easily. You could cast it though by doing: `var people = myDataTable.Rows.Cast<MyComplexPeopleModel>()` This would give you an IEnumerable of a complex type that Newtonsoft can handle.

Comment: I have created an object (called myObj) with properties of parent and child and loaded my datatable into a list of objects. So I now have a list<myObj> What is the best method to use to serialise this into my desired output?

Comment: You can use Newtonsoft: `string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's example [dataTable serialization](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer)

Or you can create `IEnumerable<ComplexData>` from dataTable and serialise

Comment: Thanks - I need to understand more before about creating IEnumberables from my data before I can figure out if this answers my question! I'll be back!