# implementing a c# interface

Tags: c#, interface, datatable

I have a dataTable called myResult which has tw columns Process and ParentProcess and I am trying to put this into an Ienumerable type so I can serialise it with Json.net.

[Original post is here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846897/serialise-a-c-sharp-datatable-with-a-hierarchy-as-json-heirachy)

Now I am up to this point, I have this interface:

```
namespace myFirstCProgramIn2013
    {
        public interface Interface1 : IEnumerable
        {
            string Process { get; set; }
            string ParentProcess { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I have implemented it in this class:

```
public class myArray : Interface1
{

    public string Process
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public string ParentProcess
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have then tried to use this class to assign myResult to it using the code below:

```
   List<Interface1> recordList = new List<Interface1>();
   if (myResult.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
       foreach (DataRow row in myResult.Rows)
       {
           var myArray = new myArray();
           myArray.Process = Convert.ToString(row["Process"]);
           myArray.ParentProcess = Convert.ToString(row["ParentProcess"]);

       }
   }
```

I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in
>   App_Web_hi4zxnmq.dll but was not handled in user code

which is thrown at the set clause of the Process Property of myArray Class.

Where am I going wrong with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you kidding? Your code throws this exception obviously

Comment: You have `throw new NotImplementedException()` all over the place so it shouldn't surprise you to get that error. Did you even try to run the code in debug mode?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to.  What don't you understand?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to. What don't you understand? - Quite a lot probably I'm trying to learn here! The Exceptions were added automatically by vs13 when I implemented the interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are throwing an NotInprementedException on the setter of the property. if you want automatic properties replace

```
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

with

```
    get; set;
```

Comment: Thanks - because the Exceptions were added automatically I assumed they were correct.